# jQuery-UI Autocomplete - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I get an SyntaxError that I don't understand with jQuery-UI Autocomplete.

Here is my code :

**PHP**

```
$productsAutocomplete = array();

foreach($products as $product){
    array_push($productsAutocomplete, $product['denomination']);
}

//$products => datas from database.
```

**jQuery**

```
function autocomplete_products(zone, products){
    $(zone).autocomplete(
        {
            source: function(request, response)
            {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(products, request.term);
                response(results.slice(0, 30));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The autocomplete work with every column of my database but not with the "denomination" one which is in "tinytext" type.

I have only text with sometimes specials characters (-,#..)

Does anyone know why it does not work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it..

It was because i had double-quotes in some element of this column.

So my array was badly formated ["Text1", "Text2 "doublequotes"", "Text3"].

I replaced it by single quote so ["Text1", "Text2 'singlequote'", "Text3"].